# Django mptt rendering item associated to parent category and sub category

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt

I am building a django app for pathology/laboratory reporting system. I need a form that will take value for different tests like (HIV-negative, some test-10). Since there are 100 and 1000 of tests and these test are grouped by categories like chemical test, microscopic test. I need to render a template with a form for these tests. I used django-mptt and building a structure in django admin seems easy but i couldn't make it work in frontend templates. Below are my project codes and descriptions.

```
class TestCategory(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Test Categories"

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Test(models.Model):
    QUALITATIVE = "1"
    QUANTITATIVE = "0"
    TEST_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (QUALITATIVE, 'QUALITATIVE'),
        (QUANTITATIVE, 'QUANTITATIVE'),
    ]
    test_category = TreeForeignKey(TestCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='test_category')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    specimen = models.ForeignKey(Specimen, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    test_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TEST_TYPE_CHOICES, default=QUALITATIVE)
    reference_text = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Price Per Unit')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['test_category']
    

# views.py

def report_create_view(request, pk): 
context ={} 
form = CreateReportForm(request.POST or None) 

if form.is_valid(): 
    patient = self.objects.all().filter(patient_id=pk)
    form.instance.patient_id = patient.patient_id
    form.save() 
        
context['form']= form 
context['patient'] = Patient.objects.all().filter(pk=pk)
context['nodes'] = TestCategory.objects.all()
return render(request, "lab/report_form.html", context) 

#template report_form.html

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load mptt_tags %}
    <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
  
   {% for node,structure in nodes|tree_info %}
        {% if structure.new_level %}<ul><li>{% else %}</li><li>{% endif %}
            {{ node.name }}
        {% for level in structure.closed_levels %}</li></ul>{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Report</button>
  </form>
```

This is what my template looks right now. As you can see my form has only categories name (I am getting TestCategory model only node the actual Test model. How can actually render tests grouped by category?

[image: result]

Comment: It's quite hard to understand your question. I suggest you group by query params "level"

Comment: @Tiana987642 may be it's more clear here https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-multi-level-category/6826

Comment: One cat have many tests right? You can write test fk to a category

Comment: Mptt should only represent structure not data

Comment: Yes one cat multiple tests or it could be cat and sub cat (may me more sub cat inside) and multiple tests. I need to query something so get results something like..

<h2>cat</h2> -category model
<input type="checkbox" name="test.name" value="test.id"> --test model
<label for="test.name"> I have a bike</label>
...and other test checkbox based on Test.test_category=TestCategory.id

**if there are sub category**
<h2>cat</h2>
<h3>sub cat</h3>
<input type=...

Comment: Check sub category existing by filter level 2, you should redesign your model